# Match, substitute and expand shell variable using perl

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

The next code perfectly works for variables without curly braces `{}`

```
export a=1 b=2 c=3
echo '$a$b_${c}_' | perl -pe 's#\$([A-Za-z_]+)#defined $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : $&#eg'
```

result `1$b_${c}_`

`b_` will never expand properly. It's okay. That problem is solved using curly braces `{}`.

The next attempt works at most good

```
echo '${a-$b}_${c}_' |perl -pe 's#\$\{?([A-Za-z_]+)\}?#defined $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : $&#eg'
```

result is `1-2_3_`. But `${a`,`$b}` should not be expanded.
I did not found a simple solution to match both braces.
Could you help with that? The problem is to match without braces or inside both braces otherwise do not match and do not substitute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pe's#\$(?:([A-Za-z_]+)|\{([A-Za-z_]+)\})#$ENV{$1//$2}//$&#eg'
```

Test:

```
$ export a=1 b=2 c=3

$ echo '$a$b_${c}_'    | perl -pe's#\$(?:([A-Za-z_]+)|\{([A-Za-z_]+)\})#$ENV{$1//$2}//$&#eg'
1$b_3_

$ echo '${a-$b}_${c}_' | perl -pe's#\$(?:([A-Za-z_]+)|\{([A-Za-z_]+)\})#$ENV{$1//$2}//$&#eg'
${a-2}_3_
```

Comment: ikegami, thank you for answer. Could you tell how `?:` works?

Comment: Does expression `$ENV{$1//$2}//$&` the same as `defined $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : $&`?

Comment: Re "*Could you tell how `?:` works?*" `(?:...)` is to regex patterns as `(...)` is to Perl and Mathematics: It groups, overriding precedence.  For example, `ab|cd` matches `ab` and `cd`, while `a(?:b|c)d` matches `abd` and `acd`. I used it to avoid repeating `\$`. As the leading character, that should make the matching more efficient.

Comment: Re "*the same as*", No. You don't even use `$2`. `f() // g()` is equivalent to `defined(f()) ? f() : g()` except that `f()` is only evaluated once, so `$ENV{$1//$2}//$&` is equivalent to `defined($ENV{ defined($1) ? $1 : $2 }) ? $ENV{ defined($1) ? $1 : $2 } : $&`